# Error in openssl s_client: "data length is too long"

Tags: ssl, ldap, certificate, openssl

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server, and I'm trying to set up Apache to authenticate using LDAPS. I ran into some problems--see [my previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/382789/certificate-problems-with-apache-ldaps-access), where I concluded that the certificate on the LDAP server was expired.

So my boss got a "real" certificate from DigiCert and installed it on `myldap.xyz.edu`. And I went to `myserver.xyz.edu` and tried `openssl s_client -connect myldap.xyz.edu:636 -showcerts`. Here's what it gives me:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140075639178912:error:1408F092:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:data length too long:s3_pkt.c:504:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 16731 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1340655299
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

...And it puts me back at the command prompt.

I looked up this "data length too long" error online, but the explanations were largely Greek to me. Is this a problem with the client or the server? Does it have to do with the certificate or something else? What can I do about it? Thanks!

**Edit:** Did some more poking around and found [this Microsoft tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051) on enabling LDAP over SSL in Active Directory (I should mention that our LDAP server is Windows Server 2003 w/ SP2 running AD). It gave me the following steps to test whether LDAPS is enabled:

> 1. Start the Active Directory Administration Tool (Ldp.exe).
> 2. On the Connection menu, click Connect.
> 3. Type the name of the domain controller to which you want to connect.
> 4. Type 636 as the port number.
> 5. Click OK.
>
> RootDSE information should print in the right pane, indicating a successful connection.

I remote-desktopped into `myldap.xyz.edu` and tried it. Here's the output I got in the right pane:

```
ld = ldap_open("myldap.xyz.edu", 636);
Established connection to myldap.xyz.edu.
Retrieving base DSA information...
Result <0>: (null)
Matched DNs: 
Getting 1 entries:
>> Dn: 
    1> currentTime: 06/25/2012 16:57:13 Central Standard Time Central Daylight Time; 
    1> subschemaSubentry: CN=Aggregate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    1> dsServiceName: CN=NTDS Settings,CN=MYLDAP,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    5> namingContexts: DC=xyz,DC=edu; CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=xyz,DC=edu; DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    1> defaultNamingContext: DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    1> schemaNamingContext: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    1> configurationNamingContext: CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    1> rootDomainNamingContext: DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    23> supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.801; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.473; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.528; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.417; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.619; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.841; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.529; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.805; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.521; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.970; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1338; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.474; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1339; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1340; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1413; 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9; 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.10; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1504; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1852; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.802; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1907; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1948; 
    2> supportedLDAPVersion: 3; 2; 
    12> supportedLDAPPolicies: MaxPoolThreads; MaxDatagramRecv; MaxReceiveBuffer; InitRecvTimeout; MaxConnections; MaxConnIdleTime; MaxPageSize; MaxQueryDuration; MaxTempTableSize; MaxResultSetSize; MaxNotificationPerConn; MaxValRange; 
    1> highestCommittedUSN: 13287969; 
    4> supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI; GSS-SPNEGO; EXTERNAL; DIGEST-MD5; 
    1> dnsHostName: MYLDAP.xyz.edu; 
    1> ldapServiceName: xyz.edu:myldap$@XYZ.EDU; 
    1> serverName: CN=MYLDAP,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=xyz,DC=edu; 
    3> supportedCapabilities: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.800; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1670; 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1791; 
    1> isSynchronized: TRUE; 
    1> isGlobalCatalogReady: TRUE; 
    1> domainFunctionality: 2 = ( DS_BEHAVIOR_WIN2003 ); 
    1> forestFunctionality: 2 = ( DS_BEHAVIOR_WIN2003 ); 
    1> domainControllerFunctionality: 2 = ( DS_BEHAVIOR_WIN2003 ); 
-----------
```

Looks like it worked, so I'm guessing Active Directory is LDAPS-ready.

**Edit 2:** Per @SilverbackNet's suggestion, I tried the `openssl s_client` command with the `-debug` option. Here is the (redacted) output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x24f3470 [0x24f34f0] (226 bytes => 226 (0xE2))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 dd 01 00 00-d9 03 02 4f f3 5a 5b 38   ...........O.Z[8
[...]
00e0 - 01 01                                             ..
read from 0x24f3470 [0x24f8a50] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 16 03 01 40 b9 02                                 ...@..
0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x24f3470 [0x24f8a5a] (16567 bytes => 2889 (0xB49))
0000 - 00 4d 03 01 4f f3 5a 5b-46 43 f0 02 76 34 1c d5   .M..O.Z[FC..v4..
[...]
0b40 - 70 3a 2f 2f 63 72 6c 33-2e                        p://crl3.
read from 0x24f3470 [0x24f95a3] (13678 bytes => 13678 (0x356E))
0000 - 64 69 67 69 63 65 72 74-2e 63 6f 6d 2f 44 69 67   digicert.com/Dig
[...]
3560 - 65 72 20 52 6f 6f 74 20-43 41 0e                  er Root CA.
356e - <SPACES/NULS>
write to 0x24f3470 [0x25027e0] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 01 00 02 02 16                              .......
---
no peer certificate available
[...]
```

From there it's the same as above. I can also post the full output from the right-hand column if that would be helpful.

**Edit 3:** We've decided to give up on this temporarily and use the Apache option `LDAPVerifyServerCert off` with the old expired certificate for the time being. :^( FWIW, my boss is now thinking that one needs to get a special, short (1024-byte, I think he said) certificate to do LDAP server verification. He knows the particulars better than I do, but this makes sense to me because the error message is saying something's too big. If/when we resolve the problem, I'll try to post the answer.

Comment: -debug in the openssl command might help, but it looks like a genuine protocol overflow. Either the cert and chain are too large (4K everything?) without the proper negotiation to expand the buffer, or there's something gone wrong in communication. Also, AD is always SSL ready from 2003 on unless you force it off in group policy.

Comment: @SilverbackNet Thanks for the ideas. I'm going to edit some output from the -debug option into my post.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this means that you're talking SSL to a non-SSL server.  Check over the configuration work on the LDAP server; the new certificate doesn't seem to be working yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should mention that LDAPS access works just fine if I specify LDAPVerifyServerCert off; I just don't want to do that. (See [my previous question](http://serverfault.com/questions/382789/certificate-problems-with-apache-ldaps-access).) So that means the server _can_ do LDAPS but just has certificate problems, right? I tried one server test I found--see my edit to the original post. Could you give more specific instructions on what I can check?

Comment: @DLosc It worked when you turned off server cert verification when you still had the old expired certificate installed - are you certain that's still the case?

Comment: Yes. When 1) the old cert is active and 2) I turn off verification, it still works. When the new cert is enabled, it fails as above. So something about the new certificate seems to be messing SSL up. Is there any chance it has to do with the certificate name? Or having multiple certificates on there at once? (My boss and I are brainstorming.)

Comment: @DLosc The LDAP server shouldn't care what the name is or anything like that - if it has a working certificate, it will use it regardless of its validity (as you've seen with it serving an expired one)  Are there any log entries from the LDAP server during its startup?  Do you have access to the certificate files so that we can verify their format, that they match, and don't have any problematic differences from the old cert?

Comment: Yeah, I'll ask my boss for the new certificate. Given @SilverbackNet's comment about AD, I don't think the problem has to do with the server startup. My boss was switching between old and new certs without restarting anything.

Comment: @DLosc Oh! That would do it.